# how to show multiple categories screen in single home screen in react native

Tags: react-native, axios, categories, hybrid-mobile-app, use-state

Here is design [image]

and here is when user press any one of category.
[image]

all categories option are on home screen upper side, and when press any of category button than home screen contents will hide and that category content will show on the same screen. It will happen on single screen in homescreen. I have api for all categories. I'm using axios. and I'm using hooks function for implemented these things. Please tell how it will happen??

Comment: What exactly are you looking for help for?

Comment: make a custom component and pass your props and show your selected category